# How to prevent function from printing?

Tags: c, gcc, printf

Is it possible to *silence* a function?
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function(){
  printf("BLAH!");
  return 10;

}
int main(){
  printf("%d", silence( function()) );
return 0;
}
```

And instead of:

```
BLAH!
10
```

I would get:

```
10
```

Is it possible? If positive how to do it?

Comment: Don't call the function... What is your intention?

Comment: It's software, almost anything is possible.  Do you want a function?  Or is a preprocessor method acceptable? How about modifying code at runtime?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29552/c (Let's discuss it over there, aye?) :)

Comment: In an interpreted language replacing `printf` with an other function that does nothing/outputs to a file/buffer would be trivial...

Comment: You could use different output streams, for example use `fprintf(stderr,...)` for messages you want to be able to discard and `fprintf(stdout,...)` for others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An awfully complicated way to do almost what you want is to use the [dup2()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) system call. This requires executing `fflush(stdout); dup2(silentfd, stdout);` before `function()` is called, and copying back afterwards: `fflush(stdout); dup2(savedstdoutfd, stdout);`. So it is not possible to do as just `silence(function())`, since this construct only allows to execute code after `function()` has already been executed.

The file descriptors `silentfd` and `savedstdoutfd` have to be prepared in advance (untested code):

```
 int silentfd = open("/dev/null",O_WRONLY);
 int savedstdoutfd = dup(stdout);
```

This is almost certainly not what you really want, but inasmuch as your question is phrased as “is it possible?”, the answer is “almost”.

Comment: Technically, you could program a C interpreter in C, have the interpreter execute the function, and ignore all `printf`s within the function. So _of course_ the answer is "yes", Turing-completeness mandates it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Why can it be evaluated to run before it is passed to the `silence`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ah, yes, you raise a good point, even `dup2()` does not quite allow what the OP would like to do, which is to write `silence(f())` to silence `f`. I will incorporate this nuance in my answer.

Comment: `silence` could be turned into a macro.

Comment: I don’t feel that this is terribly complicated, or inappropriate. Of course normally you’d use a callback / some other logic instead of `printf` to print conditionally, but if for instance you’re calling some external function (or something that you cannot change), redirecting the standard output stream is just fine. Of course OP’s syntax cannot be realised in C (but in C++ there’d be no problem) but something quite similar is possible.

Comment: The `silentfd` is actually `silentfd = open("/dev/null",O_RDONLY);`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I incorporated this suggestion and tried to expand on how to prepare `savedstdoutfd` too, but are you sure about the `O_RDONLY` part of your suggestion? I would have expected `O_WRONLY` to emulate `stdout` more closely.

Comment: You will need to `fflush()` in case your `stdout` is not line buffered.

Comment: I think you'd need to `fflush(stdout)` before changing the file descriptor, so that what had already been buffered would be printed properly.  The `dup()` function would be simpler than `dup2()` for this: `int savedstdout = dup(FILENO_STDOUT);` would save an `open()` call, which is a fairly expensive system call and still give you a previously unused file descriptor result.  And output files should be opened `O_WRONLY` (or, at a pinch, `O_RDWR` — you usually can read from stdout and write to stdin if they're the terminal).

Answer (score 8):

use macro function and null device.

E.g. for windows

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define silence(x) (_stream = freopen("NUL:", "w", stdout), _ret_value = x,_stream = freopen("CON:", "w", stdout),_ret_value)
int _ret_value;
FILE *_stream;

int function(){
  printf("BLAH!");
  return 10;

}
int main(void){
    printf("%d", silence( function()) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Macro function is not a function. It's only the appearance.

Comment: First of all one to many closing parenthesis next to function.
Second what could be correct macro version for UNIX, SunOS to be precise.
And third for a complete code example.

Comment: I think the test of environment for *nix because the Windows environment can't be but (other people to also wrote) and can do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

No its not possible. You could however try to temporarily redirect the stdout to something else. That may come close to what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this macro instead of `printf` to be able to prevent printing:

```
int flag=0;
#define PRINT(...) if(flag){printf(...)}
```

then use PRINT macro by considering the variable `flag`. If `flag==1`, the function will print and if `flag==0`, the function will not print.

Answer (score 3):

If you're designing the function do the following:

```
int function(void (*printer)(char *)){
    if (!printer)
        printer = printf;

    printer("BLAH!");
    return 10;
}

void silence(char *s){
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("%d\n", function(silence));
    return 0;
}
```

That should do what you're looking for. Unfortunately, I didn't test it and my C is probably a little bit rusty.

Of course if `function` isn't something you have control over, the answers already posted are all correct solutions.

---

Actually, if you're designing the function yourself, just do:

```
int function(int print){
    if (print)
       printf("BLAH!");

    return 10;
}


function(0);  /* Won't print anything */
function(!0);  /* Will print "BLAH!" */
```

because `0` is false and any non-zero (or `!0`) value is true. My above suggestion is error prone since you'll have to be able to mimic the `printf` signature for `silence` or for any other function you wish to use.

Comment: I am working on collaboration project so there are functions that I can not edit but for some I probably apply this work around.

Comment: If you're using function as part of a library, that library should *never* be printing anything. Everything that needs to be printed should be performed by the user. Feel free to yell at the library author. Also, certain functionality generally should be decoupled to provide reusability. Good luck with the project though.

Answer (score 3):

With [GCC extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), you might consider having macros like

```
bool silent;
#define silence(X) ({int _x; quiet(); _x = (X); verbose(); _x; })
#define printf(Fmt,...) \
  do{if (!silent) printf(Fmt,##__VA_ARGS__);}while(0)
```

<sup>that `silence` macro would work only if its argument `X` is a `int` expression (or use [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)) I also assume that the result of `printf` is never used. Recall that "recursive" macros are specially pre-processed, the inside occurrence of `printf` (in that `printf` macro) is left verbatim without macro-expansion.</sup>

Notice that `silence` cannot be a function (otherwise, its argument would have been evaluated before calling it). And you need GCC [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) extension to "remember" the result of the argument in some variable `_x` (you could generate that name using [`__COUNTER__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) and preprocessor concatenation), to give it back as the value of `silence` macro invocation.

Then you need to define your functions `quiet()` and `verbose()`, perhaps something like

```
void quiet() 
{
   silent = true;
}

void verbose()
{
   silent = false,
}
```

if you don't want to define `printf` as your macro, you could use [freopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3.html) on `stdout` (perhaps with `"/dev/null"` etc...) or do [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) tricks (like [suggested by Pascal Cuoq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16498418/841108)).

If your code base is huge, and you want something more serious and are willing to spend days or weeks of work, consider customizing your GCC compiler with a plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (or ask someone to do it). Notice that `printf` is known to GCC.

In reality, you should define your own macro like

```
#define myprintf(Fmt, ...) do{if (!silent) \
    printf(Fmt,__VA_ARGS__);}while(0)
```

and just use `myprintf` instead of `printf` everywhere, this is a portable trick. Of course, I assume you are not passing `printf` as a function pointer.

For debugging, I actually recommend

```
#define dbgprintf(Fmt,...) do{if (wantdebug) \
  printf("%s:%d:" Fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, \
          ##__VA_ARGS__);}while(0)
```

and then I use `dbgprintf("i=%d",i)` or simply `dbgprintf("foo here")` in my code.

I'm using `##__VA_ARGS__` which is a GCC extension to accept [no variable arguments](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) to a variadic macro. If you want strict C99, you will just say `__VA_ARGS__` and every `dbgprintf` would need one argument after the format.

You could also re-implement your own `printf` function, but I don't advise doing that.

(Notice that things could be more complex, you can print using `fputs` not `printf` ....)

Comment: `printf("BLAH!");` is expanded as `printf("BLAH!",);` . I can not compile with an error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you have the function explicitly printing and call it like this then it will always print. if you want to silence the function completely you could simply comment out that line.You could even use a control statement so that it only prints IF and when a condition is met otherwise it stays blank and only returns the number.