# C variadic macro do not compile

Tags: c, gcc, macros, variadic-macros

I have some issue with this code i written. GCC does not like it :

```
#define _DEBUG_ADD(string, ...)                     \
do{                                                 \
if (EVALUATE_TYPE(string)){                         \
size_t  size = strlen(string) + BUFFER_SIZE_DEBUG;  \
char    *buffer = alloca(size);                     \
bzero(buffer, size);                                \
snprintf(buffer, size, string, __VA_ARGS__);        \
fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, DEBUG_STREAM); }} \
while(0)
```

But gcc display this error :

```
../debug.h:33:42: error: expected expression before ')' token
                    snprintf(buffer, size, string, __VA_ARGS__);
```

I read the gcc doc about [variadic macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) and i am not doing it wrong.

Can someone point my mistake ? I am completly lost.

**edit :**

I use it that way

```
_DEBUG_ADD("Bbox found @ %f %f %f %f", box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]);
```

Comment: Show how you *use* that macro

Comment: Don't use a macro where a function will do as well! If you had formatted that mess properly, the problem would be obvious.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch
I use it that way :

_DEBUG_ADD("Bbox found @ %f %f %f %f", box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]);

Comment: That should go into your question (don't comment your question but edit it)

Comment: @Olaf I agree, but i want to try using a macro.

Comment: Are you sure that the backslashes are the last characters (i.e. no spaces after them) of their lines?

Comment: I don't think the example of usage you showed is the one that causes the problem, but instead it's a case where there is a format strings with no arguments after it. in such case `__VA_ARGS__` will be compiled to nothing and you will a have a comma followed by closing parentheses

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://ideone.com/0TAoYK), post [mcve]. Note `_DEBUG_ADD` is **reserved**, using this identifier is UB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502124/841108 could inspire you

Comment: You can fix that by adding two # before `__VA_ARGS__`, and then the preceding comma will be removed, e.g. `sprintf(buffer, size, string, ##__VA_ARGS__)`. I'm not posting this as an answer, as I don't know that it's the actual problem..

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sure, there is no spaces

Comment: @MByD it does not work.I normally do not need to use tokens

Comment: Assume your source is `foo.c`; get the raw preprocessed form using something like `gcc -C -E foo.c|grep -v '^#' > foo.i` then compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -c foo.i` and study carefully the error messages and *locations* (they'll point into `foo.i` and you'll understand what is wrong)

Comment: Note that names starting with an underscore and either another underscore or a capital letter are reserved to the implementation for any use.  Do not create your own names that start with an underscore (simplistic rule, but safe), or read the details from §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers in the C standard (and similar sections in other standards, such as POSIX) and follow them.  Don't use `_DEBUG_…` as a name you invent if you value your sanity.

Comment: @MichaelVouriz: So you prefer trying to jump from a roof just to see if it hurts? There are some things which are just a bad idea and don't gain any knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I take the code fragments you showed and fill in missing bits to get a complete, compilable source file, I do not get any errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _DEBUG_ADD(string, ...)                     \
do{                                                 \
if (EVALUATE_TYPE(string)){                         \
size_t  size = strlen(string) + BUFFER_SIZE_DEBUG;  \
char    *buffer = alloca(size);                     \
bzero(buffer, size);                                \
snprintf(buffer, size, string, __VA_ARGS__);        \
fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, DEBUG_STREAM); }} \
while(0)

#define EVALUATE_TYPE(s) 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE_DEBUG 128
#define DEBUG_STREAM stderr

void test(double box[4])
{
  _DEBUG_ADD("Bbox found @ %f %f %f %f", box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]);
}
```

-->

```
$ gcc -fsyntax-only -Wall test.c
$
```

This is why we make such a fuss about [minimal, *complete*, *verifiable* examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We don't want to waste a lot of time barking up the wrong tree.

However, in this case, I have a strong suspicion that your problem was actually triggered by code like *this*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _DEBUG_ADD(string, ...)                     \
do{                                                 \
if (EVALUATE_TYPE(string)){                         \
size_t  size = strlen(string) + BUFFER_SIZE_DEBUG;  \
char    *buffer = alloca(size);                     \
bzero(buffer, size);                                \
snprintf(buffer, size, string, __VA_ARGS__);        \
fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, DEBUG_STREAM); }} \
while(0)

#define EVALUATE_TYPE(s) 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE_DEBUG 128
#define DEBUG_STREAM stderr

void test(void)
{
  _DEBUG_ADD("got here 1");
}
```

which produces nearly the same error message you showed:

```
$ gcc -fsyntax-only -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘test’:
test.c:11:43: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
 snprintf(buffer, size, string, __VA_ARGS__);        \
                                           ^
test.c:21:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘_DEBUG_ADD’
   _DEBUG_ADD("got here 1");
   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

When you give `_DEBUG_ADD` no arguments after the format string, `__VA_ARGS__` expands to nothing, so the "compiler proper" sees

```
snprintf(buffer, size, string, );
```

which is indeed a syntax error.  This is what the GNU [comma-deletion extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) is for:  if you put `##` between `,` and `__VA_ARGS__`, the comma will be removed when `__VA_ARGS__` expands to nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _DEBUG_ADD(string, ...)                     \
do{                                                 \
if (EVALUATE_TYPE(string)){                         \
size_t  size = strlen(string) + BUFFER_SIZE_DEBUG;  \
char    *buffer = alloca(size);                     \
bzero(buffer, size);                                \
snprintf(buffer, size, string, ##__VA_ARGS__);      \
fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, DEBUG_STREAM); }} \
while(0)

#define EVALUATE_TYPE(s) 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE_DEBUG 128
#define DEBUG_STREAM stderr

void test(void)
{
  _DEBUG_ADD("got here 1");
}
```

-->

```
$ gcc -fsyntax-only -Wall test.c
$
```

Unfortunately, this extension is only available in GCC and Clang.  I understand the C and C++ committees are talking about adding a comparable, but incompatible, feature Real Soon Now (see the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick/5589364) and its answers, and also C committee documents [N2023](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2023.pdf) and [N2153](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2153.htm)), but even if they do, it'll probably be a decade or so before that's ubiquitous enough to use.

Incidentally, the name `_DEBUG_ADD` begins with an underscore.  All names beginning with underscores are reserved for internal use by the C compiler and library in at least some contexts.  Until you have a *lot* more experience in the language, you should not give anything in your code a name beginning with an underscore.  (It is OK to *use* things with names that begin with underscores, like `__VA_ARGS__` and `_IONBF`, but only if they are documented.)

Comment: Any URL about what the C comittee is discussing ?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502124/841108 mentioned in a comment to the question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Um, it came up in comments on another question here not so long ago.  I'm trying to dig it up now.  I hope the mods haven't deleted those comments.

Comment: [N2153](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2153.htm) looks like it is the latest document on the issue, from the 'Post-Markham Mailing'.